# combining two python lists and aggregating the values by key

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, aggregate

I have two lists seen here.

```
a = ['a','b','a']
b = [200,300,300]
```

when I print like so:

```
print dict(zip(a,b))
```

I get:

```
{'A': 300, 'B': 300}
```

How would I aggregate the values based off the keys so that I get

`{'A': 500, 'B': 300}`  ?

Answer (score 3):

```
result = {}
for k,v in zip (['a','b','a'], [200,300,300]):
  result[k] = result.get(k,0) + v
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['a','b','a'] 
b = [200,300,300]
c = Counter()
for i, j in zip(a, b):
  c[i] += j
print(c)
```

Comment: That reads more like a defaultdict approach. Using a Counter, wouldn't it be more typical to use `c.update({i:j})`?

Comment: @ChrisJohnson: I've always used the `defaultdict` approach;  I am not sure which would be more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose a clear way (per [Python's Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)) to achieve your goal is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

a = ['a','b','a']
b = [200,300,300]
d = dict()

for place, key in enumerate(a):
    try:
        d[key] += b[place]
    except KeyError:
        d[key] = b[place]
print(d)
```

Which gives your expected output:

> {'a': 500, 'b': 300}

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over zip for key and values and put them in dictionary.

```
a = ['a','b','a']
b = [200,300,300]

for key, val in zip(a,b):
    if key in combined_dict:
        combined_dict[key] += val
    else:
        combined_dict[key] = val

 print(combined_dict)
 => {'a': 500, 'b': 300}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way to do it is like below, **by avoiding zip function**,

```
aggregateDict = {}
a= ['a', 'b', 'a']
b=[200, 300, 200]
for i in range(len(a)):
    aggregateDict[a[i]] = aggregateDict.get(a[i], 0) + b[i]
```

Output will be

```
{'a': 400, 'b': 300}
```

Comment: `zip` is much better for this case

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I think zip function has more overhead than range(). Zip will creates a temporary composite container list of tuples so not good from point of memory efficiency and time complexity.

Comment: if you are using `Python 3`, than `zip` will create iterable, so no memory problems, on `Python 2` you should use [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)

Comment: getting element from list (and you are getting `a[i]` twice) obviously has more overhead than using `zip`/`izip`